# How do I add to my Quartz Job DisallowConcurrenExecution?

Tags: quartz-scheduler

How do I add to my Quartz Job DisallowConcurrenExecution?

I am new to Quartz 2.0, but I implemented a StatefulJob

Answer (score 1):

If you implement StatefulJob, then you automatically inherit the @DisallowConcurrenExecution annotation.

You can instead tag your class with the annotation (and other related annotation for re-persisting the JobDataMap after execution) - and not implement StatefulJob and have the same affect.